# How to find ssh keys from a specific users when they are not located in the /home/{USER}/ directory?

Tags: ssh, security

I have discovered that in one of the servers I am using, the SSH Keys are not in the /home/{USER}/.ssh/ directory. I am sure they exist because when I tried to generate a new pair of keys it says that they exist in other directory.

I wonder if there any way to get the location of the SSH Keys without trying to generate a new pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard openssh implementation of *ssh* has a line, in */etc/ssh/sshd_config* which states:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

which may have been modified in your case. Otherwise, try  *find*:

```
 find . -type f -exec file {} + | grep public
```

Comment: Great answer. I realized that the home folder was changed, and effectively the keys were there. Do you know if ssh key can be in a different directory? I mean, not in the home directory

Comment: @LorenzoLerate Yes, but you need to inform the ssh daemon (*sshd*) where to search for it, and you do that by changing the instruction I mentioned in my answer.